# I am unable to print the fi value outside the function

Tags: python, function, printing, return

```
s= input("enter the string to be checked")
def pig(s):
    first=s[0]
    if first in "aeoui":
        fi=s + "ay"
    else:
        fi=s[1:]+first+"ay"

return fi
```

Comment: You should learn what a global variable is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return `fi`

```
s= input("enter the string to be checked") 
def pig(s): 
    first=s[0] 
    if first in "aeoui": fi=s + "ay" 
    else: fi=s[1:]+first+"ay"
    return fi
fi = pig(s)
print(fi)
```

OR
make `fi` a global variable that can be accessed from anywhere

```
s= input("enter the string to be checked") 
def pig(s): 
    global fi
    first=s[0] 
    if first in "aeoui": fi=s + "ay" 
    else: fi=s[1:]+first+"ay"
pig(s)
print(fi)
```

Comment: `global` is arguably one of the worst solutions (especially for beginners), I would recommend to use simple OOP principles instead when `return` is not suitable